# How can I calculate Financial year from created date using SQLite

Tags: sqlite, concatenation, date-arithmetic, strftime

Suppose I say my Financial year start date is 2000-02-01.
Then Financial year should be

```
2019-03-01 to 2020-02-29
2020-03-01 to 2021-02-28
2021-03-01 to 2022-02-28
.
.
.
```

I want to show a column of the financial year like below using SQLite.

| Product | created Date | Financial Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2019-05-28 | FY 2019-2020 |
| Apple | 2020-01-15 | FY 2019-2020 |
| Banana | 2020-04-22 | FY 2020-2021 |
| Mango | 2021-10-15 | FY 2021-2022 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a separate table.

All you need is the function `strftime()`:

```
SELECT *,
       'FY ' || strftime('%Y', createdDate, '-2 month') || '-' ||
       strftime('%Y', createdDate, '-2 month', '+1 year') FinancialYear
FROM products;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9a170cc680eaf0f05b542ab9648e4d80).

Comment: Thanks, buddy this is what I am looking for

Comment: what change I would have to do to show the start date of the financial year and end date of the financial year  in a separate column?

Comment: @Shambhusharan check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=686da132b7130610a8f709083d34f345

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `createdDate REAL` and `CASE WHEN`:

```
select Product,
  date(createdDate) as createdDate, 
  case when (abs(strftime('%m', createdDate)) < 3)
       then 'FY ' || cast(strftime('%Y', createdDate) - 1 as text) || '-' || strftime('%Y', createdDate)
       else 'FY ' || strftime('%Y', createdDate) || '-' || cast(strftime('%Y', createdDate) + 1 as text)
  end AS FinancialYear
from `products`;
```

See the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0aef1c7fbe2ebc48b60aa8a27bc16878)

Comment: this is also working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect maintaining a separate table which contains the custom financial year ranges along with the text label you want to display for each:

```
financial_years:

start_date | end_date   | label
2019-03-01 | 2020-02-29 | FY 2019-2020
2020-03-01 | 2021-02-28 | FY 2020-2021
2021-03-01 | 2022-02-28 | FY 2021-2022
```

Now all we need to do is join your table of products to the above table:

```sql
SELECT p.Product, p.created_date, fy.label
FROM products p
INNER JOIN financial_years fy
    ON p.created_date BETWEEN fy.start_date AND fy.end_date;
```

Comment: how to generate financial year. I have the start date of the Financial year. can we write some query that generates Financial Year Table/View with created date from another table?

Comment: I am suggesting that you store the custom date ranges for each financial year in a separate table, along with the labels.  Then, join to this table.